# Have cognitive scientists dealt with Kant’s idea of a priori knowledge using their tools?

Tags: kant, knowledge, cognitive-sciences, knowledge-representation, cognitive-psychology

Since Kant’s concept of a priori knowledge is about how humans perceive and construct the world in their head, that sounds very directly related to cognitive science and psychology. Have scientists tried to make these connections?

Comment: Cognitive scientists are interested in knowledge acquisition mechanisms, not in their epistemological status, so *a priori* are of little interest to them (and the idea of *a priori* in Kant's absolute sense is almost universally rejected today anyway). But his model of mental faculties and their function in knowledge acquisition is largely incorporated into modern cognitive psychology, see SEP, [Kant’s View of the Mind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-mind/#1) and [Where Kant Has and Has Not Influenced Contemporary Cognitive Research](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-mind/#6).

Comment: @Conifold I didn’t mean to suggest cognitive scientists ponder over philosophical issues. I simply meant the aspect of Kant arguing that people perceive the world with certain built-in concepts and spectacles, and those should be of interest to cognitive scientists. For instance, if we are “hardwired” to experience space and time, cognitive scientists should be interested in figuring out why.